# Access GCP cloud Storage bucket from docker container without using gcloud utility

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-kubernetes-engine, gcsfuse

I have a docker file that needs to access the GCP bucket. I do not want to authenticate GCP using SA and gcloud utility (`gcloud auth activate-service-account <<gcp account>> --key-file=<<serviceaccount>>.json` due to security violence.

I want to use a different authentication approach with security compliance.

Could anyone please help with the same?

Comment: Can you share your dockerfile and the platform on which you are running/building it?

Comment: `code` FROM centos:7

ENV MNT_POINT /var/s3fs

RUN yum clean all && yum update -y

RUN echo $'[gcsfuse]\n\
name=gcsfuse (packages.cloud.google.com)\n\
baseurl=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/gcsfuse-el7-x86_64\n\
enabled=1\n\
gpgcheck=1\n\
repo_gpgcheck=0\n\
gpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg\n\
       https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg\n'\
>> /etc/yum.repos.d/gcsfuse.repo

RUN yum -y install gcsfuse

RUN mkdir -p "$MNT_POINT"

Comment: above is my docker file. In docker file, I need to write authentication for GCP.

Comment: Where are you building your container? On your workstation? on cloud build?

Comment: I build the docker image and run the container as a pod in GKE cluster.

Comment: You also build the container in GKE? You use a container with docker installed on it, you mount a volume with your sources and your run the build, right? Just to be sure to reproduce the same environment context on my side.

Comment: Build the container in GKE but docker won't be installed on it. I need to log in to GCP without an SA JSON key or log in using any encrypted key mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **API authentication** to access GCP bucket instead of using ‘gsutil’ and client library authentication.

To make requests using OAuth 2.0 to either the Cloud Storage [XML API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/overview) or [JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1), include your application's access token in the Authorization header in every request that requires authentication. You can generate an access token from the [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/).

```
Authorization: Bearer OAUTH2_TOKEN
```

Use the list method of the Objects resource.

```
GET /storage/v1/b/example-bucket/o HTTP/1.1

Host: www.googleapis.com

Authorization: Bearer’ ya29.AHES…….gSwg’
```

To authorize requests from the command line or for testing, you can use the curl command with the following syntax:

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer OAUTH2_TOKEN "https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/BUCKET_NAME/o"

For local testing, you can use the ‘gcloud auth application-default print-access-token’ command to generate a token.

Due to the complexity of managing and refreshing access tokens and the security risk when dealing directly with cryptographic applications, we strongly encourage you to use a verified [client library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#libauth).

[Cloud storage authentication](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#oauth) for additional information.